# How run Adobe After Effects CS6 v6.0.335.0 64-bit software into 32-bit machine?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, adobe-after-effects

I'm using windows 7 32-bit OS other configuration is below in image.

[image: configuration]

In my system I'm trying to install Adobe After Effects CS6 v6.0.335.0 here is the setup screenshot

[image: setup image]

but after running the setup I'm getting this error

[image]

Now this software is 64bit and I'm using 32-bit architecture machine. So how can I install 64bit software in 32bit machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can't.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7)

> **Can I run 64-bit programs on a 32-bit computer?**
>
> If the program is
>   specifically designed for the 64-bit version of Windows, it won't work
>   on the 32-bit version of Windows. (However, most programs designed for
>   the 32-bit version of Windows do work on the 64-bit version of
>   Windows.)
>
> Device drivers designed for the 64-bit version of Windows don't work
>   on computers running a 32-bit version of Windows. To learn how to
>   check for drivers, see Update a driver for hardware that isn't working
>   properly or go to the device manufacturer's website. You can also get
>   information about drivers by going to the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor
>   webpage.

You will need to get a 32 bit version of [Adobe After Effects.](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/cs6-32bit.html) - In this situation, you are able to install CS4 for 32 bit by contacting customer support with your CS6 serial key - you should be given a valid key.

> This package has been removed in the CS6 versions of these suites. **But
>   it's available upon request for customers who have other mission
>   critical programs that require a 32-bit OS. Adobe offers this
>   continued legacy support for a limited time**. If you use a 32-bit OS,
>   begin transition plans now.

It's worth noting that you have 6GB of RAM installed, but with a 32 bit OS it's not possible to address all of this. It may be worth considering installing a 64 bit version of Windows 7 to address all of your available RAM, as well as installing this software. 64 bit Windows is backwards compatible with 32 bit programs, but not vice-versa.

Comment: Note the 'support package' is simply the CS4 installer of AE. They haven't compiled AE CS6 for 32-bit OS.

Comment: @Mulvya Amended my answer, thank you for pointing this out.